# VB script to echo out file names from one location to another including sub folders

Tags: vbscript, powershell-2.0

source: Network location UNC path
Destination: Remote server and would like to run the script on this server.

I have been looking many scripts but couldn't match my exact requirement. Below is the VBscript which looks closer to my requirement but this is not working for subfolders and it looks to be hours specific and I am looking for days specific of multiple file types. Any help is much appreciated ?

Thanks in advance for helping me out !

I am okay with any other script but my requirement has to be fulfilled.

======================================================

```
Option Explicit 

On Error Resume Next

Dim fso, FileSet, Path, File, DDiff, Date1, Date2, DestPath

Path = "C:\source"
DestPath = "\\server\destination\" 
'DestPath must end with \
FileSet = GetDirContents(Path) 

For each File in FileSet 
Set File = fso.GetFile(Path & "\" & File)
Date1 = File.DateLastModified 
'.DateCreated if you want 24hrs of life, this example is 24hrs since last written
Date2 = Now()

DDiff = Abs(DateDiff("h", Date1, Date2))

If DDiff >= 168 Then
If Not fso.FileExists(DestPath & File.Name) Then
File.Move DestPath
'wscript.echo File.Name
Else
wscript.echo "Unable to move file [" & File.Name & "]. A file by this name already exists in the target directory."
End If
End If
Next 

Function GetDirContents(FolderPath) 
Dim FileCollection, aTmp(), i 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set FileCollection = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath).Files 

Redim aTmp(FileCollection.count - 1) 
i = -1 

For Each File in FileCollection 
i = i + 1 
aTmp(i) = File.Name 
Next 

GetDirContents = aTmp 
End Function
```

========================================================================

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateDiff` function with "d" as interval (for Day) insted of "h" (for Hour). And the rest of the question is how to make this recursive function, right?

MoveByDate "C:\source", "\server\destination\", 7

```
Sub MoveByDate(SrcPath, DestPath, DaysDiff)
    Dim oFSO, oFile, oFolder, oSubFolder, Date1, Date2
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(SrcPath)
    Date1 = Now

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Date2 = oFile.DateLastModified
        If Abs(DateDiff("d", Date1, Date2)) >= DaysDiff Then
            If Not oFSO.FileExists(DestPath & oFile.Name) Then
                oFile.Move DestPath
            End If
        End If
    Next

    For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        MoveByDate oSubFolder, DestPath, DaysDiff
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: yes, I would like that to be a recursive function.

I tried checking running the script in my local machine.

That isn't seem working at my end. I am trying to execute from command prompt and its not working.

No error message. It does nothing.

Comment: Did you check arguments you pass to MoveByDate? 3th is a days difference, that in the example code here is 7 (1 week). If there not so older files, then obviously there nothing to move.